# Can I add a value to a Named Range?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have a Named Range setup in an Excel worksheet which I'm using to supply values for a Data Validation drop-down. My source formula is, basically, this:

```
=INDIRECT( "OnePartOfTheRangeName" & "AnotherPart" )
```

The range changes based on another value in the row, so that's why I have to combine strings, etc.

I want to add an extra value to the Data Validation list but am not having any luck with that. I thought that if there was some sort of "Union" function I could combine the INDIRECT list with the single value, but I haven't been able to find such a function.

Does anyone know another way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Excel is quite specific in its error message (indeed, rather a nice change!):

[image: SO12207603 example]

so I doubt worth too much effort in attempting a direct approach. And I am bearing in mind that over three years without a solution to a fully understandable question probably means "it is not possible".

However an indirect approach might serve, though for that some details *may* be missing - for example how your named range is being constructed at present. For the purposes of illustration, assume that is named `Part1` and refers to R1:R12, with blanks at the end (to allow room for expansion) and blanks in the middle (to show versatility). Assume 'another part' is named `Part2` and refers to S1:S10, also with blanks in the middle and at the end (and also at the start).

The Data Validation might then be a List whose Source: `=whole` is the range T1:T22 named `whole`.

T1 would then be populated with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Part1,SMALL(IF(ISBLANK(Part1),"",ROW(Part1)-MIN(ROW(Part1))+1),ROW(A1))),IFERROR(INDEX(Part2,SMALL(IF(ISBLANK(Part2),"",ROW(Part2)-MIN(ROW(Part2))+1),ROW(A1)-SUMPRODUCT(--NOT((ISBLANK(Part1)))))),""))
```

(courtesy of Get Digital Help) entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down to T22.

This is dynamic in that adding an entry in ColumnR for example adds that into ColumnT which in turn adds into the validation drop-down.

Disadvantages include that the dropdown is not sorted in order if `S` and `T` entries are not sorted and the 'room for expansion' remains evident in the drop-down.